# Any way to prevent input via an iOS 3rd party keyboard?

Tags: html, ios, custom-keyboard

I noticed that in some `<input>` fields, using a 3rd party iOS keyboard like Swype or SwiftKey doesn't always work so well, especially when there are listen events checking for key presses. Is there some way to force the iOS keyboard to switch to the built-in default on certain `<input>` or `<textarea>` fields?

Example of something that behaves differently between the iOS keyboard and 3rd party keyboards:

http://jessepollak.github.io/card/

I'd like to point out that the problem lies in the fact that the third party keyboard doesn't trigger `keyup`, `keypress`, etc. This is why I'm looking for a way to force the iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a way to do this, it would be better to resolve the problem and have the code listen key presses where possible but be able to handle all sorts of input methods such as speech recognition driven input which would produce similar issues. I went through that path with my games and received nothing but complains until I fixed it. Users don't like to be restricted very often.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in the web code, it's that the 3rd party keyboard doesn't seem to trigger keypress events.

Comment: Not all keyboards trigger keypress events. Swipe type keyboards return one whole word at a time. keypress event occur when user PRESS a key. It is a form of input method that is not supported in the web code. It doesn't mean that there is a problem with the code. It means that the code needs to evolve to keep up with these kind of changes.

Comment: Well, regardless of any of these philosophies, the original question was if there is some way in HTML/HTML5 to make an input/textarea field force the iOS built-in keyboard.

Comment: You not taking advantage of advice doesn't mean that others won't. This is what's good about this platform :)

Comment: What advice? The bottom line is, I have no control over 3rd party keyboards. And if I need to make something happen on a `keypress` event, it won't work unless the user is using the default iOS keyboard. Hence my question. A good answer could've been something like "no, it's not currently possible."

Comment: The bottom line is, software is developed for the user's convenience not the developers. Developers should not have control over what type of keyboard the user should use. However, they can choose whether to support it or not.

And YES, it is technically possible prevent input via an iOS 3rd party keyboard by rendering your own keyboard but that's not an acceptable solution to many.